# How to display an element on top of the overlay?

Tags: css

I am trying to show a table on top of the overlay. The overlay `div` has the following styles:

```
.overlay { display:none; position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%;
           height:100%; z-index:999; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); }
```

At some point in my code, I do the following:

```
$("body").append(`<div class="overlay"></div>`)
$(".overlay").css("display", "block");
$("table").addClass(".table-top"); // Supposed to show my table on top of the overlay
```

The last statement adds the following to my `table`:

```
.table-top { position: fixed; z-index:9999; }
```

However, nothing changes, and the table remains "under" the overlay. Meanwhile, the `body` is set to `position: relative;`. I tried to play with `position`, `background`, `z-index`, but had no luck. Is there a problem with my `overlay` or `table`? Thank you

Comment: Please create a working example so we can see what is happening. [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/) is a great place to put the code, or you can just post the code here (please make it as short as possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the dot in your `.addClass` statement, where you add the table-top class.

```
$("table").addClass(".table-top");
```

should be

```
$("table").addClass("table-top");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5caeLcn0/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the class which has the css is different to what is being added by the js. Does it work if you use

table-top { position: fixed; z-index:9999; }